# Can't seem to refresh Blazor page in finally block

Tags: blazor, azureservicebus

I'm trying to get my page to refresh regardless of hitting an exception or not. With the code below, if a user clicks on a message that is currently locked by another user it will pop up with an error, but it does not run the code and refresh the page in my finally block after catching the error.

```
async Task GetPayment(GridRowClickEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = args.Item as NewPayment;
            sessionId = item.SessionId;
            selectedPayment = new NewPayment();
            

            receiver = await sbService.CreateReceiver(queue, sessionId);
            receivedMessage = await receiver.PeekMessageAsync();

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.Body);
            selectedPayment = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NewPayment>(message);
            paymentWindow = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            toastType = MatToastType.Danger;
            Toaster.Add(ex.ToString(), toastType, "", "", configure =>
            {
                configure.VisibleStateDuration = 100000;
                configure.ShowCloseButton = true;
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            await GetListOfPayments();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

GetListOfPayments() code:

```
async Task GetListOfPayments()
    {
        try
        {
            newPayments = new List<NewPayment>();
            newPayments = await sbService.ListPaymentsInQueue(queue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            toastType = MatToastType.Danger;
            Toaster.Add(ex.ToString(), toastType, "", "", configure =>
            {
                configure.VisibleStateDuration = 100000;
                configure.ShowCloseButton = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

I have no problems having the toaster pop up during the catch. I have tried moving GetListOfPayments() to the catch and it doesn't work. The only way I have gotten this to work is like this:

```
async Task GetPayment(GridRowClickEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {

            var item = args.Item as NewPayment;
            sessionId = item.SessionId;
            selectedPayment = new NewPayment();
            **newPayments = null;**

            receiver = await sbService.CreateReceiver(queue, sessionId);
            receivedMessage = await receiver.PeekMessageAsync();

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.Body);
            selectedPayment = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NewPayment>(message);
            paymentWindow = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            toastType = MatToastType.Danger;
            Toaster.Add(ex.ToString(), toastType, "", "", configure =>
            {
                configure.VisibleStateDuration = 100000;
                configure.ShowCloseButton = true;
            });
        }

        finally
        {
            **if (newPayments == null)
            {
                await GetListOfPayments();
                StateHasChanged();
            }**
        }
    }
```

This resets my data grid before it runs the code to fetch the selected payment, but it does refresh the data grid with an updated list of payments. Ideally I'd like to only run GetListOfPayments() if there is an error, or at least wait until after fetching the selected payment. Is that possible?

I'm also using Azure ServiceBus to create a real time queue of pending payments. I'm not 100% sure this is the correct approach. Any Advice is welcome!

Comment: Which DataGrid?  Verify what happens with `<p>@newPayments?.Count</p>` without setting it to null.

Comment: I'm using Telerik Grid, and the count on newPayments = 3.

Comment: Is your Grid bound to a List or an ObservableCollection?  With the Telerik Grid, you may be better off binding to an ObservableCollection to ensure UI is refreshed as expected.

Comment: I updated my code to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List, and I'm still seeing the same results.

paymentCollection = new ObservableCollection<NewPayment>();
paymentCollection = await sbService.ListPaymentsInQueue(queue);

Comment: Still, show the details - this is more about that Grid than about Blazor+finally.